# karma testing - services injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

i have inhereted a angular project that uses npm, grunt, bower ... and karma + jasmin.
i have been asked to setup some tests for the project using karma and jasmin.
karma has already been setup in the project but never used.
when i run 'grunt test' i get injection errors on all of the services, like the following.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: excelparserserviceProvider <- excelparserservice
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unprp0=excelparserserviceProvider%20%3C-%20excelparserservice

there is already a karma.conf.js looking like this.
i havent changed anything in the karma.conf file, except adding some of the libaries that used in the project into the list under Files: [].

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',

      // i manually added the ones from here
      'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'app/bower_components/geocoder-js/dist/geocoder.js',
      'app/bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'app/bower_components/d3/d3.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js',
      // to here.
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

the paths,

'app/scripts/*.js' --> leads to app.js and a config.js

'app/scripts/**/*.js' -->leads to all services controllers and directives

'test/mock/**/*.js' --> is non existent

'test/spec/**/*.js'--> contains all the test files

there are test files corresponding to every part of the applikation. Which i have been told has been auto generated. So i find it weird if they should contain the error. but the one related to the excpelparserservice injection error is.

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: excelparserservice', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('batchUploadApp'));

  // instantiate service
  var Excelparserservice;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_excelparserservice_) {
    Excelparserservice = _excelparserservice_;
  }));

  it('should do something', function () {
    expect(!!Excelparserservice).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

the declaration of the service looks like this.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('batchUploadApp')
.service('ExcelParserService',
  function ExcelParserService($q, ExcelvalidationService, GeoLocationService) {
```

the application in general works.

hope i my explication is usefull :)
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to inject `_ExcelParserService_`? It could as well be just a case-sensitivity problem ||| edit: that's most likely the case, I tried it locally in one of my projects and yes, cases must match.

Answer (score 0):

You define and register your service like this:

```
angular.module('batchUploadApp').service('ExcelParserService', ...
```

meaning that you register it under the name `ExcelParserService`. On the other hand, when you try to inject the service into you test, you use its name in lowercase:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_excelparserservice_) {
```

Both names must match, thus the solution is to change the name of the parameter:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_ExcelParserService_) {
```